# How do I convert a floating-point number into a hex string in Perl?

Tags: perl, floating-point

To be quite certain that my calculations are correct for all cases, I want to see the result (a double precision number) as a hex or binary string. How can I get a hex/binary string or a byte representation of this number in `Perl`? In `Java`, I could use, for instance,

```
double d = performMyCalculations();
System.out.format("%x\n", Double.doubleToLongBits(d));
```

for this purpose, and it will print `3fc3333333333333` for `0.15`. How can I get a similar result in `Perl`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perl's [pack()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [unpack()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) functions allow you to cast binary representations back and forth.

```
my $double_bits = unpack "Q", pack "d", 0.15;
printf "%x\n", $double_bits;
# Output: 3fc3333333333333
```

The `pack "d"` packs a double as its binary representation. With `unpack "Q"` we unpack this bit pattern as an unsigned 64-bit integer. So this reinterprets/casts the bit pattern of a double to an integer, which we can then output with hex digits.

Perl also has a formatting option to display hexadecimal floating point:

```
printf "%a\n", 0.15;
# Output: 0x1.3333333333333p-3
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. I've heard about `pack/unpack`, even have read the perldoc, but have not understood too much at a glance. You see, Perl is not my speciality :)

Comment: Or just: `say unpack H*', pack 'd', 0.15;`